# Vert.x: how to process HttpRequest with a blocking operation

Tags: spring, multithreading, rest, vert.x

I've just started with Vert.x and would like to understand what is the right way of handling potentially long (blocking) operations as part of processing a REST HttpRequest. The application itself is a Spring app.

Here is a simplified REST service I have so far:

```
public class MainApp { 
   // instantiated by Spring
   private AlertsRestService alertsRestService;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(alertsRestService);
   }
}

public class AlertsRestService extends AbstractVerticle {
  // instantiated by Spring
    private PostgresService pgService;
    @Value("${rest.endpoint.port:8080}")
    private int restEndpointPort;

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> futureStartResult) {
        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        //enable reading of the request body for all routes 
        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

        router.route(HttpMethod.GET, "/allDefinitions")
              .handler(this::handleGetAllDefinitions);

        server.requestHandler(router)
            .listen(restEndpointPort, 
                result -> {
                    if (result.succeeded()) {
                        futureStartResult.complete();
                    } else {
                futureStartResult.fail(result.cause());
                    }
                }
            );
    }

  private void handleGetAllDefinitions( RoutingContext routingContext) {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        Collection<AlertDefinition> allDefinitions = null;
        try {
            allDefinitions = pgService.getAllDefinitions();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatusCode(500).end(e.getMessage());
        }           
        response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .setStatusCode(200)
            .end(Json.encodePrettily(allAlertDefinitions));
    }

}
```

Spring config:

```
    <bean id="alertsRestService" class="com.my.AlertsRestService"
      p:pgService-ref="postgresService"
      p:restEndpointPort="${rest.endpoint.port}"
    />
    <bean id="mainApp" class="com.my.MainApp"
      p:alertsRestService-ref="alertsRestService"
    />
```

Now the question is: **how to properly handle the (blocking) call to my postgresService**, which may take longer time if there are many items to get/return ?

After researching and looking at some examples, I see a few ways to do it, but I don't fully understand differences between them:

**Option 1.** convert my AlertsRestService into a *Worker Verticle* and use the worker thread  pool:

```js
public class MainApp { 
   private AlertsRestService alertsRestService;
        
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true);
       Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(alertsRestService, options);
   }
}
```

What confuses me here is this statement from the Vert.x docs: *"Worker verticle instances are never executed concurrently by Vert.x by more than one thread, but can [be] executed by different threads at different times"*

Does it mean that all HTTP requests to my alertsRestService are going to be, effectively, throttled to be executed sequentially, by one thread at a time? That's not what I would like: this service is purely stateless and should be able to handle concurrent requests just fine ....

So, maybe I need to look at the next option:

**Option 2.** convert my service to be a *multi-threaded Worker Verticle*, by doing something similar to the example in the docs:

```js
public class MainApp { 
   private AlertsRestService alertsRestService;
        
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
     DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions()
    .setWorker(true)
    .setInstances(5) // matches the worker pool size below
    .setWorkerPoolName("the-specific-pool")
    .setWorkerPoolSize(5);
     Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(alertsRestService, options);
   }
}
```

So, in this example - what exactly will be happening? As I understand, "*.setInstances(5)*" directive means that 5 instances of my 'alertsRestService' will be created. I configured this service as a Spring bean, with its dependencies wired in by the Spring framework. However, in this case, it seems to me the 5 instances are not going to be created by Spring, but rather by Vert.x - is that true? and how could I change that to use Spring instead?

**Option 3.** use the *'blockingHandler'* for routing. The only change in the code would be in the AlertsRestService.start() method in how I define a handler for the router:

```js
boolean ordered = false;
router.route(HttpMethod.GET, "/allDefinitions")
 .blockingHandler(this::handleGetAllDefinitions, ordered);
```

As I understand, setting the 'ordered' parameter to TRUE means that the handler can be called concurrently. Does it mean this option is equivalent to the Option #2 with multi-threaded Worker Verticles?
What is the difference? that the async multi-threaded execution pertains to the one specific HTTP request only (the one for the /allDefinitions path)  as opposed to the whole AlertsRestService Verticle?

**Option 4.** and the last option I found is to use the *'executeBlocking()'* directive explicitly to run only the enclosed code in worker threads. I could not find many examples of how to do this with HTTP request handling, so below is my attempt - maybe incorrect. The difference here is only in the implementation of the handler method, handleGetAllAlertDefinitions() - but it is rather involved... :

```js
private void handleGetAllAlertDefinitions(RoutingContext routingContext)    {
  vertx.executeBlocking(
      fut -> { fut.complete( sendAsyncRequestToDB(routingContext)); },
      false,
      res -> { handleAsyncResponse(res, routingContext); }
  );
}

public Collection<AlertDefinition> sendAsyncRequestToDB(RoutingContext routingContext) {
  Collection<AlertDefinition> allAlertDefinitions = new LinkedList<>();
  try {
      alertDefinitionsDao.getAllAlertDefinitions();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500)
        .end(e.getMessage());
  }
  return allAlertDefinitions;
}

private void handleAsyncResponse(AsyncResult<Object> asyncResult, RoutingContext routingContext){
  if(asyncResult.succeeded()){
      try { 
          routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .setStatusCode(200)
            .end(Json.encodePrettily(asyncResult.result()));
      } catch(EncodeException e) {
           routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500)
             .end(e.getMessage());
      }
   } else {
      routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500)
        .end(asyncResult.cause());
   }
}
```

How is this different form other options? And does Option 4 provide concurrent execution of the handler or single-threaded like in Option 1?

Finally, coming back to the original question: **what is the most appropriate Option for handling longer-running operations when handling REST requests?**

Sorry for such a long post.... :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a big question, and I'm not sure I'll be able to address it fully. But let's try:

In Option #1 what it actually means is that you shouldn't use ThreadLocal in your worker verticles, if you use more than one worker of the same type. Using only one worker means that your requests will be serialised.

Option #2 is simply incorrect. You cannot use `setInstances` with instance of a class, only with it's name. You're correct, though, that if you choose to use name of the class, Vert.x will instantiate them.

Option #3 is less concurrent than using Workers, and shouldn't be used.

Option #4 `executeBlocking` is basically doing Option #3, and is also quite bad.

Comment: Thank you, Alexey! So, looks like the best option is #1... I'm still not sure how I can truly scale it out though - I definitely don't want serial access to my handlers... Sounds like one way is to create and deploy multiple instances of my AlertsRestService verticles. If that's true - should each verticle instance create it's own HttpServer  and Router, on different ports, maybe? Or should my MainApp do that and pass the same instance of the HttpServer to each verticle's instance? Also, looks like I'd have to create instances of AlertsRestService via Spring's context.getBean() ... Thanks!

Comment: The way to truly scale is to create a pipeline for verticles that communicate through EventBus. One HTTP server is more than enough for routing. You can also follow this presentation: https://www.slideshare.net/AlexeySoshin/concurrency-with-vertx